# Best practice to design a small view, e.g. for background information

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, user-interface

I'm currently working on my first iOS app which will be available on the Appstore soon (I hope ;-) and the project requieres a view with background information. What should display the view? The view should display a icon, opening times and one or two small grouped tables with references two other views with additional information like FAQ or contact informations from the authors.

My question is now. What is the best practice to create such kind of view? Is it better too design the view with the Interface Builder and hardcode the strings of the view or should create a UITableView with different Section headers and heights? Where come the content from? plist or so?

I don't know, whats the best practice is and I hope someone can me tell his opinion to solve such a kind of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really a matter of taste and the nature of the data you want to display. I find Interface Builder to be a great tool for setting up the basic layout of a view and try to use it as much as possible.

If your data is static and will never change, I see no reason to not just hardcode it in IB or the delegate methods of your `UITableView`s. On the other hand, if your data is likely to change, or is fetched from a backend, you would be better off setting the text in your `UIViewController`.

Plists are great for holding data that you want to display and they have great support in iOS. If your data will change from time to time, this would be my choice. However, there is really no need for using the extra CPU cycles to parse the plist every time you run the app if the data will never change.